# How to set the values selected in select2 list box in MVC application?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using Select 2 List box in my mvc application. From that list box user can select the values from the dropdown and he can enter the values whatever he wants.

[image]

In the above picture Allergy and skin is coming from Drop down and the Text 'usertyped' is typed by user

I can able to post and store all the data including user typed values. But the problem is i am not able to set that values selected in the list box after the user posting the form.

Below is my code:

Modal:

```
public class SegmentList
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }    
        public string Segname { get; set; }    
        public int? SegId { get; set; }    
        public int? Active { get; set; }    
        public List<string> List { get; set; }    
        public List<SegmentList> seglist { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
@model selectTokenization.Models.SegmentList



@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace}))
{


    <div class="col-md-2  col-xs-2">Associated Segment</div>
    <div class="col-md-4  col-xs-4">

            @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.List, new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.List, "Segname", "Segname", Model.List.AsEnumerable()), new { @class = "form-control tokenizationSelect2", @multiple = "multiple" })
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12  col-xs-12">
        <div class="pull-right" style="padding:1%;">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="btnSaveProbDiagnosis" type="submit" name="">save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}


<link href="~/Scripts/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/select2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".tokenizationSelect2").select2({
        placeholder: "Select Segment", 
        tags: true,
        tokenSeparators: ['/',',',';'," "]
    });
})
</script>
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {

            List<SegmentList> li = new List<SegmentList>();
            li.Add(new SegmentList { Segname = "Select", SegId = 0 });
            li.Add(new SegmentList { Segname = "Allergy", SegId = 1 });
            li.Add(new SegmentList { Segname = "Skin", SegId =2 });
            li.Add(new SegmentList { Segname = "Hair", SegId =3 });
            li.Add(new SegmentList { Segname = "Fever", SegId = 4 });
            li.Add(new SegmentList { Segname = "USA", SegId = 5 });
            li.Add(new SegmentList { Segname = "All", SegId = 6 });
            SegmentList obj = new SegmentList();
            obj.seglist = li;
            ViewBag.List = li;
            return View(obj);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(SegmentList Segment)
        {
            MyModal db = new MyModal();
            string segmentIds = string.Empty;
            foreach (string s in Segment.List)
            {
                segmentIds += s + ",";
            }
            Segment obj = new Segment();
            obj.Segname = segmentIds.TrimEnd(',');
            obj.SegId = 1;
            obj.Active = 1;
            db.Segments.Add(obj);
            db.SaveChanges();



            List<SegmentList> li = new List<SegmentList>();
            li.Add(new SegmentList { Segname = "Select", SegId = 0 });
            li.Add(new SegmentList { Segname = "Allergy", SegId = 1 });
            li.Add(new SegmentList { Segname = "Skin", SegId = 2 });
            li.Add(new SegmentList { Segname = "Hair", SegId = 3 });
            li.Add(new SegmentList { Segname = "Fever", SegId = 4 });
            li.Add(new SegmentList { Segname = "USA", SegId = 5 });
            li.Add(new SegmentList { Segname = "All", SegId = 6 });
            SegmentList obj1 = new SegmentList();
            ViewBag.List = li;
            return View(obj1);
        }
```

Comment: Did you tried to init your form again after posting, with the new value add in database? The idea: 1/ The user write something 2/ you insert it in database 3/ you init your form again fetching the new data. With ajax the user won't see it

Comment: Do not post duplicate questions!

Comment: Was there a solution for this?